# Tables of data associated to reductive algebraic groups?

Tags: reference-request, algebraic-groups

I am looking for a reference that contains lots of calculations for specific examples of various objects one can associate to a reductive algebraic group.  For example, given a (specific) linear algebraic group $\mathbb{G}$, I would like to know things like:

-a maximal compact subgroup of $\mathbb{G}(\mathbb{R})$

-the rank of $\mathbb{G}(\mathbb{R})$

-a Borel subgroup for $\mathbb{G}$

-the Lie algebra of $\mathbb{G}$

-a Cartan involution for $\mathbb{G}$

I assume these things are well known to people who study algebraic groups.  I just can't find a place where specific examples are worked out (or even stated) in any detail.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I think these lectures are enough good

1.[Real Reductive groups II](http://iecl.univ-lorraine.fr/%7ENicolas.Prudhon/gnc/bibliographie/HarmonicAnalysis/%5BNolan_Wallach%5D_Real_Reductive_Groups_II_No._2%28BookFi.org%29.pdf), Wallach

2.[ALGORITHMS FOR COMPUTATIONS IN LOCAL SYMMETRIC SPACES](http://www4.ncsu.edu/%7Eloek/research/rootsystem-algorithms1.pdf), JENNIFER R. FOWLER AND ALOYSIUS G. HELMINCK*

3.[Lectures on Algebraic Groups,](http://www.math.tifr.res.in/%7Edprasad/alg-grp.pdf) Dipendra Prasad

4.[Lectures on Algebraic Groups](http://darkwing.uoregon.edu/%7Eklesh/teaching/AGLN.pdf), Alexander Kleshchev

5.[LECTURES ON SHIMURA CURVES 4.5: A CRASH COURSE ON LINEAR ALGEBRAIC GROUPS](http://alpha.math.uga.edu/%7Epete/SC5-AlgebraicGroups.pdf) , PETE L. CLARK

6.[Structure Theory of Reductive Groups through Examples](http://math.stanford.edu/%7Emakisumi/articles/reductivegroups.pdf), Shotaro Makisumi.

7.[Reductive Groups](http://www.jmilne.org/math/CourseNotes/RG.pdf), J.S. Milne

8.[INTRODUCTION TO REDUCTIVE GROUP SCHEMES OVER RINGS](http://www.math.ens.fr/%7Egille/prenotes/reductive.pdf), P. GILLE

9.[Introduction to actions of algebraic groups](http://www-fourier.ujf-grenoble.fr/%7Embrion/notes_luminy.pdf), Michel Brion

Comment: I had a course with Michel Brion, In my openion his lectures are the best.